# SQL Server: schema access through stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, database, database-schema

I have two schemas, `schema_ui` and `schema_logic`.

`schema_logic` is for privileged users and I will define my tables in this schema. `schema_ui` is for restricted users with limited functionality, so they cannot access the tables in `schema_logic`.

I create a `sp_ReadTable1` in `schema_ui` and this stored procedure reads from `Table1` in `schema_logic`. user1 has restricted permission and can only access, `schema_ui`. Now user1 has access to `sp_ReadTable1` but can he actually execute it, as the stored procedure reads from table1?

So, something like C# public method, which returns private members...

Comment: For something like this I use `WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER` on all SPs in the schema, create a role that grants execute permissions on that schema and assign the user to the role.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!